# Complete and Sufficient Statistics from Two Samples

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from $N(\epsilon,\sigma^2)$ and let $Y_1,...,Y_m$ be a random sample of size $m$ from $N(\eta,2\sigma^2)$.
>
> Find a vector of complete and sufficient statistics for $(\epsilon, \eta, \sigma^2)$.

I know that, individually, each normal distribution can be written in the form of the linear exponential family, and even with both $\epsilon$ abd $\sigma^2$ unknown, a typical vector of complete and sufficient statistics is given by $\left< \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right>$.  However, considering that $\sigma^2$ appears in the second population as well, do I need to somehow use the other data points (the $y_is$) to get a complete and sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$?  I'm not sure anymore.

**So this is my main concern: what is the complete and sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$ in this scenario?**

EDIT:

I've written the joint likelihood as:
$$L_1(\vec X)L_2(\vec Y)=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\epsilon)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\sum^m_{j=1}(y_j-\eta)^2}{4\sigma^2} 
         \right)}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}(4\pi\sigma^2)^{m/2}}$$

This implies that the joint likelihood can be written in the following linear exponential family form:

$$L_1(\vec X)L_2(\vec Y)=\frac{P(\vec X, \vec Y)e^{\vec T(\vec X, \vec Y) \cdot \vec w(\vec \theta)}}{q(\vec\theta)}$$

Where $\cdot$ represents the dot product, $\vec T(\vec X, \vec Y)=\left< 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m y_j^2, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \sum_{j=1}^m y_j\right>$, $\vec\theta=\left< \sigma^2,\epsilon,\eta\right>$, $\vec w(\vec \theta)=\left<-\frac{1}{4\sigma^2},\frac{\epsilon}{\sigma^2},\frac{\eta}{2\sigma^2}\right>$, $P(\vec X, \vec Y)=1$, and finally $q(\vec \theta)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}(4\pi\sigma^2)^{m/2}e^{\frac{n\epsilon^2+m\eta^2}{4\sigma^2}}$.

Hence the joint likelihood can be written in the form of the linear exponential family, which immediately implies that a complete and sufficient statistic for $\left< \sigma^2,\epsilon,\eta \right>$ is given by:

$$\left< 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m y_j^2, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \sum_{j=1}^m y_j\right>$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You should start by writing out the full Likelihood: $L(\epsilon, \eta, \sigma^2|data) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\prod_{j=1}^mf(y_j)$. Then try to use factorization theorem to get an answer.

Comment: You should add the self-study tag (since you have used five tags already, you will need to remove one of them)

Comment: A sufficient statistic is associated with the _whole_ parameter, not a subset. You hence need to factorise the _full_ likelihood to exhibit this sufficient statistic, then establish it is complete.

Comment: @Xi'an I have edited my answer; am I on the right track?